# unctuosity vs. unctuousness (what is more colloquial?)

Tags: word-usage

> unctuosity vs. unctuousness

Both of the words are in their noun forms. What is more colloquially used?

First one is a noun itself and second one is a noun consisting of adj. and suffix -ness. Is there any usage difference between them?

Comment: Try looking them up. That said, neither is "colloquial". The adjective is more common: Don't be unctuous. Also, not "colloquial".

Comment: Could you tell me what the difference is?

Comment: Neither word is at all common. "Unctuousness" seems to be more common in writing: [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unctuousness%2Cunctuosity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunctuousness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunctuosity%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both words are sufficiently rare that there is no store of usage to compare.

"Unctuosity" has some very limited use to describe the oiliness of some wines.

"Unctuousness" seems to mostly limited to Indian Auyrvedic descriptions of hair and skin, and to feminist theory.

Most native speakers (except Michael) never use these words.  The adjective "unctuous" has some more use. But it's not colloquial.

Comment: I can use, and have used, unctuosity to mean 'the quality of being excessively flattering or ingratiating'. A particular case was when describing how Norman St John Stevas, a British Member of Parliament, spoke on the subject of the royal family. Many Church of England clergy displayed the quality in the past, now mainly the present Archbishop of Canterbury. I might use the literal, physical meaning to talk about the greasy or lubricant properties of an ointment, lotion, or fatty substance.